# jQuery getting tag's content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

First of all, I know my question seems to be already asked many many times but I'm facing a weird issue.

Here's the situation :

I've got an integer (dynamically loaded) in this tag :

`<i id="my_id">{{here's my integer}}</i>`

What I want to do is to retrieve the integer inside my  tag but this integer is set to 0 at first (When the page isn't fully loaded") and then 2 or 3 seconds later, this integer is set to its real value.

So I tried something like this :

```
var test = 0;
$('#my_id').change(function(){
  test = $('#my_id').html();
});

console.log(test);
```

This always returns me 0. I tried many things to get the current value of my tag but I can't find a way to succeed. Can you please help me get this integer ?

Cordially, Rob.

Comment: Well, I'm using AngularJs and Rails, quite difficult to make a fiddle with all I've got in my app :/

Comment: There isn't anything that envokes the `change`. The jQuery code is basically saying... when the element with `#my_id` is changed, do this. You could attach a click event or run it as a self-executing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event is only fired by `input` elements. You can try polling the value like so:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var value = parseInt($('#my_id').text(), 10);

    if(value > 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        //... do stuff
    }

}, 250); //poll every 250ms
```

Another way is to fire a custom event when you change the value:

```
//Somewhere in your code where you set the value in the i tag:
$('#my_id').text(value);
$('#my_id').trigger("valueChanged");

//Elsewhere in your code
$('#my_id').on("valueChanged", function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    if(value > 0) {
        //... do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, man, you just saved my evening, many many thanks ! (Will mark it as accepted asap !)